# CORS при отправке и получении

Tags: node.js, request, cors

опять вопрос про CORS
поднимаю сервер на 9000м порту на nodejs + node modules express ( в браузере - работает )
поднимаю второй проект, на котором делаешь API запрос к серверу
в консоле вижу - Provisional headers are shown,
хотя вроде всё прописано

Господа, посоветуйте, как правильно отправить и принять запрос?

```
// server
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
    res.send({})
})

app.listen("9000")


// и ест-но охота получить эти данные ( в ответе -> [] )
fetch("http://localhost:9000/api", {
    headers: {
        "Allow": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {console.log('+++')})
.catch(e => console.error(e))
```

p.s.
да, про CORS уже тыщу раз писали, но вот вроде все заголовки учтены, и прям теряюсь, что не та

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin используется в ответе, а не в запросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы шлете заголовок который не был разрешен - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` и `Allow` который шлет сам браузер, даже если его не указать

Для того чтобы их разрешить нужно заменить:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
```

на

```js
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Allow,Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
```

или разрешить любые заголовки так:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
```

Так же хочу обратить внимание что заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` должен отдавать сервер и его не требуется отправлять с браузера на клиенте, так что можно его убрать.